# Selenium webdriver - failed to locate descendant object

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, descendant

I have a registration page.

In my test, I'm trying to register without a first name.
Pressing the register button should display the a 'Required' notification label.

You can see the structure in the attached screenshot.
I tried to get the text from the id `'firstName'` by xpath, id, etc. It failed to locate this object.

My latest attempt:

```
String test = driver.findElement(By.id("'firstName'/descendant::td[@class='alert alert-danger']")).getText();`
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: i think by By.id is the wrong method try By.css, also the div with class alert is NOT a descendant of #firstname

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Tried that - but found out that the paste is not exactly like the original and edit it to be like the original is not so simple and in the end, receive a wrong answer from you guys. Thanx for the comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `By.cssSelector("#firstName + registration-control-messages > div.alert")`

The `By` you are using is not correct.

Comment: Simplified your CSS selector. You had a lot of stuff in there that was using more of an XPath syntax.